# Compare-Object between 2 Csv columns

Tags: powershell

I tried this syntax

```
$Csv1 = Import-Csv -Header C1,C2 -delimiter ";" csv1.csv
$Csv2 = Import-Csv -Header C1,C2 -delimiter ";" csv2.csv
Compare-Object $Csv1.C2 $Csv2.C2
```

I get an exception :

ParameterBindingValidationException

I don't want syntax for basic arrays I want for csv imported with import-csv.

In Csv1 file I have a list of strings like :

```
Max Rate;Max_Rate
Min Rate;Min_Rate
```

In Csv2 file I have a list of strings like :

```
Max Rate;Max_Rate
Min Rate;Min_Rate
Average Rate;Average_Rate
```

Comment: You're going to have to give some more information on what you're trying to do. Have you looked at the help for `Compare-Object`?

Comment: Of course but they do give syntax for Array

Comment: Please show the code for how you generate $Csv1 and $Csv2

Comment: @EBGreen hi, I updated

Comment: What's in `csv1.csv` and `csv2.csv`?

Comment: Does this work? ***Compare-Object ($Csv1 | Select -Expand C2) ($Csv2 | Select -Expand C2)***

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I updated.

Comment: @EBGreen I tried with the data above, I have no error but no output.

Comment: I tried the code that you posted with the data that you posted and got the proper output indicating the Average_Rate was in the right (csv2.csv) file. I think that you have something else going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you posted and the contents of the CSV files your results should be :

```
InputObject                                                               SideIndicator                                                            
-----------                                                               -------------                                                            
Min_Rate                                                                  =>                                                                       
Average_Rate                                                              =>                                                                       
Max_Rate                                                                  <=
```

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted to be causing the results you are getting, so I assume that you are having a different issue that isn't outlined in your question..

Only thing I can think of is how are you viewing/editing these csv files? I would try just to type `$Csv1` or `$Csv2` just to see that the output is there before trying to compare.

The only other reason you would not be getting output is if the two objects you are comparing are actually the same. Compare-Object returns the objects that differed. Otherwise, this cmdlet does not generate any output.

Comment: OK thanks I made a stupid error : I duplicated first file modified it but forgot to save the change.